# Problems rendering multiple NodeJs queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to render several queries in a view with Nodejs but the console returns Promise {pending }.

Please help, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function (req, res, next) {
const{id} = req.params;
const linksUpdate = db.query('SELECT L.id,L.title,L.url,L.description,U.fullname,U.id FROM links AS L INNER JOIN users AS U ON L.user_id=U.id WHERE L.id = ?'[id], (error, results, fields) => {
if (error) throw error;
const users = db.query("SELECT U.id, U.username, U.password, U.fullname FROM users AS U", (error, resp, 
fields) => { if (error) throw error;
  console.log(linksUpdate);
  console.log(users);
   res.render('links/edit', {linksUpdate: linksUpdate,users: users
     });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either move your logic inside the callbacks of `db.query()` like

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res, next) {
   const { id } = req.params;
   db.query('SELECT L.id,L.title,L.url,L.description,U.fullname,U.id FROM links AS L INNER JOIN users AS U ON L.user_id=U.id WHERE L.id = ?' [id], (error, linksUpdate) => {
        if (error) return next(err);
        db.query("SELECT U.id, U.username, U.password, U.fullname FROM users AS U", (error, users) => {
            if (error) return next(err);
            console.log(linksUpdate);
            console.log(users);
            res.render('links/edit', {
                linksUpdate: linksUpdate,
                users: users
            });
        });
    });
});
```

or await the returned promises instead of using callbacks as explained in detail here: https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-async-await-6fb25b01b628